# Flutter FireStore ,Try to get array of collection from array of document by one request

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, collections

I have an application under construction I want to access, in FIRESTORE I have several countries as a doc and within each country I have a collections and inside the collections I have a list of doc I need access to all.

### Example:

[image]

### My Code:

```
Stream<List<RecentChat>> getFavo({userId , countryName}) { 
    List<CountryModel> country;
    for(CountryModel c in countryName) {
        var ref = _db.collection('country').doc(c.countryName).collection('chat').where("likes", arrayContains: userId).snapshots(); 
        return ref.map((snap) => snap.docs.map((doc) => RecentChat.fromJson(doc.data())).toList());
    }
}
```

**Current Behavior:** Only the first doc is returned.

**Desired Behavior:** Return all the docs.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Stream<List<RecentChat>> getFavo({userId , countryName}) {
    List<CountryModel> country;
    for(CountryModel c in countryName) {
      var ref = _db
          .collection('country')
          .doc(c.countryName)
          .collection('chat').where("likes", arrayContains: userId)
          .snapshots();

      return ref.map((snap) =>
          snap.docs.map((doc) => RecentChat.fromJson(doc.data())).toList());
    }

  }

Comment: However, only the first doc is returned

Comment: add that code to your question, it's unreadable like this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed only the first element will be returned, since you are doing a `return` in side of the loop and not using the `Stream` keyword `yield`.

### Example:

```
Stream<List<RecentChat>> getFavo({userId , countryName}) { 
    List<CountryModel> country;
    for(CountryModel c in countryName) {
        var ref = _db.collection('country').doc(c.countryName).collection('chat').where("likes", arrayContains: userId).snapshots(); 
        yield ref.map((snap) => snap.docs.map((doc) => RecentChat.fromJson(doc.data())).toList());
    }
}
```

Comment: Only the first doc is returned. :(

Comment: Stream<List<RecentChat>> getFavo({userId , countryName}) async*{
    for(CountryModel c in countryName) {
      var ref = _db
          .collection('country')
          .doc(c.countryName)
          .collection('chat').where("likes", arrayContains: userId)
          .snapshots();
      
       yield* ref.map((snap) => snap.docs
            .map((doc) => RecentChat.fromJson(doc.data())).toList());
    }
  }